# c# CsvWriter no header for first object and header for second object

Tags: c#, csv

This is the CSV Configuration

```
 public static CsvConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
    {
        return new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            SanitizeForInjection = false,
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            Delimiter = ","
        };
    }
```

I need to create a CSV file with two objects, for first I do not need to write header but I need for the second to write the header.

```
 csvWriter.WriteRecords(firstObject); //just a text line
 csvWriter.WriteHeader<secondObjects>();
 csvWriter.NextRecord();
 csvWriter.WriteRecords(secondObjects);
```

If I use attribute  [Ignore] then I have two empty rows.

[image]

Comment: Use NextRecord to skip first line.

Comment: because I have HasHeaderRecord = true on configuration when I run this line 
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(firstObject); //just a text line

it automatically writes me the header of firstObject 
and I do not want this header to be on file

Comment: I never use the library.  I can easily do it in c# without added library and do not have the headaches when the library doesn't work.   Lot of people have the issue with the library.  Every time I recommend not using the library I get a lot of negative comments.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear with out a proper [Mre].
But it seems boils down to:

- How to not write Header with configuration `HasHeaderRecord=true`?
- How to write Header with configuration `HasHeaderRecord=false`?

#### 1/. `HasHeaderRecord=true`

With this configuration `WriteRecords` will write the header.
This is the expected behavior:
You want to write all the elements of a collection, the configuration tell you that there is a header so you will write a header before the element.

But `WriteRecord` wont. It's logical to not write headers for each records.

```
foreach(var item in records){
    csv.WriteRecord(item);  
    csv.NextRecord();
}
```

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5GhAnb)

---

Important:
`WriteRecords` ≠ `WriteRecord` , notice the **s**.
It's in fact Write_All_Records vs Write_One_Record

#### 2/. `HasHeaderRecord=false`

The other way around is to not write header automatically and do it programmatically using `csv.WriteField("FieldName")`.

```
//Write the Header
csv.WriteField("C");        
csv.WriteField("D");
csv.NextRecord();

csv.WriteRecords(datas);
```

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rBxgqg)

Comment: Thank you, I use HasHeaderRecord=false and I solve my issue( I use Reflection to get objects name)

Comment: @alex, Im not a fan of reflexion. That's why I put this one in Sencond. Cause I feel like it's easier to simply enumerate Item than enumerate Properties name. Especially because you loose all the CsvHelper Naming and Mapping configuration. You have to make sure you enumerate the Property in the same order that CsvHelper will write the row.

Comment: The first solution look more robust and easier. Have you check the Live demo? My code may be clearer than my english.

Comment: yes, I know reflection is not a good solution, I will try to find a better solution

Comment: Set header to true, use `WriteRecord(xyz)` and `NextRecord()` for the one without header. And `WriteHeader<type>` for the one with header. It's not about bad reflexion it's about Csv helper mapping feature. With reflexion it will be hard to write the header in a different order like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-by-index. Have name that does not match the properties Name https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-by-name. Write the same property multiple time with different Name.

Comment: thank you very much @xdtTransform, I used what you explained to me and it works very well